# A neat way to apply many (300) methods to one data

Tags: c++, qt

I need to apply a lot of functions to the same piece of data in arbitrary order. Different people add different functions. I have created a system, that, after simplification, looks like that:

**abstract_filter.h**

```
class AbstractFilter {
    void filter(data) = 0;
}
```

**blue_filter.h**

```
class BlueFilter: public AbstractFilter ...
red_filter.h ...
green_filter.h ...

parser.cpp
#include "blue_filter.h"
#include "red_filter.h" //so on

void Parse(const Data data) {
    RedFilter redFilter();
    redFilter.filter(data);
    BlueFilter blueFilter();
    blueFilter.filter(data);
    ....
}
```

I have hundreds of filters and people always forget to add them to the list or configure. Is it possible to write something like "take all classes from that group/folder and instantiate and put in array...."? I can't make them static or register filters in their constructors because several filtering stacks can be active in the same time.
All I want is to not have to manually enumerate all filters. Would be great to put them in place by just adding them to the project.

Comment: Create an array of `AbstractFilter*` and execute the `filter` method for every item in the array?

Comment: You could write a script to generate the necessary code by examining the directory.  Make the script a pre-build step (if you're using something like Visual Studio) or just a dependency if you're using a makefile.

Comment: I think the following phrase should have been explained better, so it would be obvious whether that ordinary solution is really unavailable vs. just not thought through "I can't ... register filters in their constructors because several filtering stacks can be active in the same time."  (And by "in their constructors" I assume we mean "in a base class constructor").

Comment: Adding to array is still listing manually all of them. And I can't add filter to array in filter constructor because there would be several arrays.

Comment: If they *register* you can create as many instances as you need. What you register is a factory method, not an instance.

Answer (score 0):

Write a python script which parses the filter directory entries an adds them to a generic factory or processing class. If the script runs on every build process the filters will always be taken care of.